# Creating a dataframe of Unique Values for each column from another DataFrame

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, distinct-values

I have a dataframe with some 60+ columns. Out of these, about half are categorical (non-amount columns). Though, some of them have categorical data stored as 1s and 0s, so datatype will be int or float if it has NaN.

I need to create a new dataframe with selected columns in earlier dataframe as index and unique values as the column.

Test Data is as under:

```
data = pd.DataFrame({'A':['A','B','C','A','B','C','D'],
                 'B':[1,0,1,0,1,0,1],
                 'C':[10,20,30,40,50,60,70],
                 'D':['Y','N','Y','N','Y','N','P']
                })
```

I did this to get the selected columns from all columns and get unique values for each column.

```
cols = itemgetter(0,1,3)(data.columns)
uniq_stats = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Val'],index=cols)
for each in cols:
    uniq_stats.loc[each] = ';'.join(data[each].unique())
```

However, this fails for those columns where the data is categorical but stored in 1s and 0s, and for those columns where there are Null values.

Expected Outcome for Above Test Data:

```
    Val
A   A;B;C;D
B   1;0
D   Y;N;P
```

What should I do to get those as well?
I'd like if Null value is also included in the list of unique values.

Comment: can you add your expected output?

Comment: So I tried %timeit all these alternatives. Seems like my version works better with my dataset (1 million rows and 60 columns) if I just need unique values. But iloc works if I need to access data from the dataframe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html) for columns by positions and then add lambda function in [`DataFrame.agg`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.agg.html):

```
df = data.iloc[:, [0,1,3]].agg(lambda x: ';'.join(x.astype(str).unique())).to_frame('Val')
print (df)
       Val
A  A;B;C;D
B      1;0
D    Y;N;P
```

Similar idea is convert only unique values, so should be faster:

```
df = data.iloc[:,[0,1,3]].agg(lambda x:';'.join(str(y) for y in x.unique())).to_frame('Val')
print (df)
       Val
A  A;B;C;D
B      1;0
D    Y;N;P
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay. I tried the map() function to do this and I think it works. Now includes both numeric categories and nan values in the list of unique values.

```
cols = itemgetter(0,1,3)(data.columns)
uniq_stats = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Val'],index=cols)
for each in cols:
    uniq_stats.loc[each] = ';'.join(map(str,data[each].unique()))
```

However, please share if there's a better and faster way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use `.stack()` with `.groupby.unique()`

```
selected_cols = ['A','B'] 
s = data[selected_cols].stack(dropna=False).groupby(level=[1]).unique()
s.to_frame('vals')

           vals
A  [A, B, C, D]
B        [1, 0]
```

another way using melt.

```
pd.melt(data).groupby('variable')['value'].unique()


variable
A                    [A, B, C, D]
B                          [1, 0]
C    [10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70]
D                       [Y, N, P]
Name: value, dtype: object
```

Comment: Hey thanks for sharing these alternatives. I tried these and they do work for all the columns. Any way to incorporate column selection in this? For the test data in question, I do not want to include column 'C'.